# Docker doesn't find file

Tags: docker

I'm working on a project that uses a Docker image for a specific feature, other than that I don't need docker at all so I don't understand much about it. The issue is that Docker doesn't finds a file that is actually in the folder and the build process breaks.

When trying to create the image using `docker build -t project/render-worker .` the error is this:

```
Step 18/23 : RUN bin/composer-install  && php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/bin  && php -r 'unlink("composer-setup.php");'  && php /bin/composer.phar global require hirak/prestissimo
 ---> Running in 695db3bf2f02
/bin/sh: 1: bin/composer-install: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c bin/composer-install  && php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/bin  && php -r 'unlink("composer-setup.php");'  && php /bin/composer.phar global require hirak/prestissimo' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

As mentioned the file **composer-install** does exist and this is what's in it:

```
#!/bin/sh

EXPECTED_SIGNATURE="$(wget -q -O - https://composer.github.io/installer.sig)"
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
ACTUAL_SIGNATURE="$(php -r "echo hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php');")"

if [ "$EXPECTED_SIGNATURE" != "$ACTUAL_SIGNATURE" ]
then
    echo 'ERROR: Invalid installer signature'
    rm composer-setup.php
fi
```

Basically this is to get composer as you can see.

This is the Docker file:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN echo 'deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libpq-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    ffmpeg \
    imagemagick \
    wget \
    git \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    unzip \
    mencoder \
    parallel \
    ruby-dev
RUN apt-get -t stretch-backports install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libav-tools \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    pcntl \
    pdo_pgsql \
    pgsql \
    soap \
    gd \
    zip

RUN gem install compass
RUN a2enmod rewrite

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER root
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP root

EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Configuring apache to run the symfony app
COPY config/docker/apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
RUN echo "export DATABASE_URL" >> /etc/apache2/envvars \
 && echo ". /etc/environment" >> /etc/apache2/envvars

RUN wget -cqO- https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.15.3/node-v10.15.3-linux-x64.tar.xz | tar -xJ
RUN cp -a node-v10.15.3-linux-x64/bin /usr \
 && cp -a node-v10.15.3-linux-x64/include /usr \
 && cp -a node-v10.15.3-linux-x64/lib /usr \
 && cp -a node-v10.15.3-linux-x64/share /usr/ \
 && rm -rf node-v10.15.3-linux-x64 node-v10.15.3-linux-x64.tar.xz

RUN bin/composer-install \
 && php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/bin \
 && php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" \
 # Install prestissimo for dramatically faster `composer install`
 && php /bin/composer.phar global require hirak/prestissimo

RUN APP_ENV=prod APP_SECRET= DATABASE_URL= AWS_KEY= AWS_SECRET= AWS_REGION= MEDIA_S3_BUCKET= \
    GIPHY_API_KEY= FACEBOOK_APP_ID= FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET= \
    GOOGLE_API_KEY= GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID= GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET= STRIPE_SECRET_KEY= STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET= \
    THEYSAIDSO_API_KEY= REV_CLIENT_API_KEY= REV_USER_API_KEY= REV_API_ENDPOINT= RENDER_QUEUE_URL= \
    CLOUDWATCH_LOG_GROUP_NAME= \
    php /bin/composer.phar install --no-interaction --no-dev --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-scripts \
    && php /bin/composer.phar clear-cache

RUN npm install \
 && node_modules/bower/bin/bower install --allow-root \
 && node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt

# Don't allow it to keep logs around; they're emitted on STDOUT and sent to AWS
# CloudWatch from there, so we don't need them on disk filling up the space
RUN mkdir -p var/cache/prod && chmod -R 777 var/cache/prod
RUN mkdir -p var/log && ln -s /dev/null var/log/prod.log \
    && ln -s /dev/null var/log/prod.deprecations.log && chmod -R 777 var/log

CMD ["/usr/bin/env", "bash", "./bin/start_render_worker"]
```

Like I said, unfortunately I don't have the slightest idea of how docker works and what's going on, just that I need it. I'm running docker in Win10 Pro and to make matters even worst it is actually working for another dev running Win10. We tried a few things but we can't make it work. I tried cloning the repo in other locations with no success at all. Everything before this particular step runs correctly.

---

[**EDIT**]

As suggested by the users I ran `RUN ls bin/` before the composer install line and this is the result:

```
Step 18/24 : RUN ls bin/
 ---> Running in 6cb72090a069
append_captions
capture
composer-install
concat_project_video
console
encode_frames
encode_frames_to_gif
format_video_for_concatenation
generate_meme_bar
image_to_video
install.sh
phpcs
phpunit
process_render_queue
publish_docker_image
run_animation_worker
run_render_worker
run_render_worker_osx
start_render_worker
update
Removing intermediate container 6cb72090a069
```

As you can see `composer-install` is there so this is quite baffling.

Also I checked and set the line ending sequence to LF and the result is the same error.

---

[**SECOND EDIT**]

I added `COPY  bin/composer-install /bin`
Then `RUN ls bin/`
And the results are the same. The `ls` command finds the file but the error persists. Also adding a slash before bin doesn't change anything :(

Comment: Docker runs as a separate operating system and does not see any file from outside the system image unless you explicitly copy it in. This may be done with COPY/VOLUME commands. If you are already using either, we need to see the whole Dockerfile to advice.

Comment: Can you post your full Dockerfile?

Comment: Have you added the ADD or COPY command in your Dockerfile. It would be good if you post your dockerfile here.

Comment: @MBer As I mentioned the file does exists in the `bin/console` folder. The option is to do something like this: `COPY bin/composer-install`?
@Mihai I posted the complete dockerfile.
Thanks for your help

Comment: could also be that the file endings of your script file are wrong weirdly it gives the same error message

Comment: @jonathanHeindl Very unlikely. The docker file comes from a private repo that I fetch twice everyday to stay up-to-date with any changes in it.

Comment: @Rodrigo that mihgt actually be the cause of the problem (if you edit your file on a windows os it might change file endings depending on your git settings )

Comment: @jonathanHeindl I haven't edited the file. As I mentioned I don't know the first thing about docker, is just part of the project's setup. I tried cloning the repo into a fresh folder and ran the build command with the `--no-cache` flag to create a fresh one and it always dies in the same step `18/23` and for the exact same reason: `/bin/sh: 1: bin/composer-install: not found`

Comment: @Rodrigoput a / in front of the bin (most likely)

Comment: Is `bin/composer-install` inside `/app`?

Comment: @jonathanHeindl Tried and didn't worked. Got the same error `/bin/sh: 1: /bin/composer-install: not found`
@matanper There is no `/app` folder. The `bin/` folder is on the root of the repo, same as the `dockerfile`, like `package.json` and `.gitignore`.

Comment: @Rodrigo I think matanper meant whether the file is present in the /app folder inside your Docker instance (your Dockerfile sets /app as the working directory). Thanks for your answers - putting them together, it sounds like we can rule out a copy error.  I stripped your dockerfile down to 4 steps (`FROM`, `WORKDIR`, `COPY`, `RUN`) with a one-line bin/composer-install file and it worked on Linux. This makes the others' Windows proposals more likely.

Comment: @MBer Where/how can I see the docker instance? As I said this is quite beyond my capabilities and part of the project I'm working on.

Comment: @Rodrigo During the build process, before the instance can be reached with `docker exec`, you have to add any commands to the Dockerfile. `RUN find bin` anywhere between the `COPY` and the bad `RUN` will print whatever is in the instance's `bin` folder.

Comment: @Rodrigo before you do the run add `RUN ls /` to see if the file actually exists at that point

Comment: then if it doesnt add `COPY <pathtocomposer-install> /bin` before the run

Comment: if it does here is some elaboration on my line endngs idea : if you check out a git repro on a windows host git might convert the linux file endings to windows ones on checkout /pull to see if this was the case open the composer-install file with notepad and goto edit -> format line endings-> and set them to UNIX (LF) then see if it works (also the / before bin still needs to be there otherwise you are using a relative path to your current WORKDIR)